# Software Testing (Dynamic, Manipulate, DynamicModule) Interfaces

Tags: front-end, dynamic, testing-and-verification

The main Testing Framework (in both the frontend and Wolfram Workbench) supports unit testing for command-line invocations. Is there a natural way of co-opting this, or perhaps there already exist user-developed idioms/packages for similar support being extended to more general testing for dynamic interfaces such as those created with `Dynamic` `Manipulate` and `DynamicModule`?

Comment: I imagine something along the lines of progressing testing/storing local variable settings done either programmatically or after interface manipulation.

Comment: Those are small examples but maybe it can be of use for you: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118568/5478

Comment: Yes, I suppose one can use a dialog to check appearances and remind you what to check in unit-tests. Kind of defeats the purpose though of being able to completely automate such testing (maybe some sort of ML training on output within certain appearance bounds would address this?) - does seem like a new front-end testing framework is needed.