# Testing Framework applications in the FrontEnd area

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization, testing-and-verification

I understand that user interaction with GUI can't be tested automatically but some things can be tested using *low-level notebook programming* functions. Are there any guidelines or limitations of using them in the Mathematica testing framework?

For example, the following code checks if a bug described in [InputAliases and SelectionPlaceholder issue in V10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55734/5478) is still present.

```
SetOptions[
  EvaluationNotebook[],
  InputAliases -> {"[" -> 
     RowBox[{"\[LeftDoubleBracket]", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 
       "\[RightDoubleBracket]"}]}
  ];

RawBoxes@"\\[AliasDelimiter]["
oCell = NextCell[];
SelectionMove[oCell , After, CellContents];

NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], "\\[AliasDelimiter]"]

( NotebookDelete[oCell]; # ) & @ FreeQ[NotebookRead @ oCell , "\[Placeholder]"]
```

But it fails in Testing Notebook whether expected output matches or not. I understand why, but

- can I easily integrate such tests into Testing Framework, assuming I will only use Notebook interface to test them? (so no `.wlt` and testing scripts involved)

Answer (score 5):

I think this question is a mistake from my side but I also think this answer may be useful for future visitors.

---

#### testing involves *low level notebook programming*

It seems I was just expecting from this to be too forgiving, if you make your functions self contained, independent from `EvaluationNotebook[]`, it will work quite fine.

```
Module[{nb, oCell},
   nb = CreateDocument[{Cell@BoxData@"\\[AliasDelimiter]["}, 
     InputAliases -> {"[" -> RowBox[{
       "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[RightDoubleBracket]"}]}, 
     Visible -> False
   ];

   oCell = First@Cells[nb];

   SelectionMove[oCell, After, CellContents];

   NotebookWrite[nb, "\\[AliasDelimiter]"];

   (NotebookClose[nb]; #) &@FreeQ[NotebookRead@oCell, "\[Placeholder]"]
]
```

[image]

---

#### testing requires user interaction

If so, let's ask the user :)

```
ChoiceDialog[
 Column[{
   "Do you see a blue clipping plane behind the sphere?",
   DocumentNotebook[{ExpressionCell[
      DynamicModule[{vp}, {vp} = 
        Options[Graphics3D, ViewPoint][[All, 2]];
       Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Red, Blue], Sphere[]}, Axes -> True, 
        ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
        ClipPlanes -> Dynamic@{Append[vp, 1]}, 
        ClipPlanesStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2], Blue]]], "Notebook",
       "Input"]}, StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]


   }],
 {"Yes" -> True, "No" -> False}
 ]
```

I've added `DocumentNotebook` so user can open example with new window where `Default.nb` options kick in. Dialog prevents rotation of graphics etc, which can be solved but that's shorter solution.
[image]